# Prepare statement not deallocate memory

Tags: mysql, go

I have daemon which continuously inserting data in mysql and returning me to `LastInsertId()` . When i start daemon its working perfect for first approx 150 000 entries. After that execution get stopped with following error

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x28 pc=0x45af73]
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
insert, _ := db.Prepare("insert into info set id=?,tg=?, adddate=now() ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tgs=1")

for {
    res, _ := insert.Exec(id, tg)
    insertid, _ := res.LastInsertId() //Getting error on this line
}
```

I am running 10 GOROUTINES, Its gives same error with single goroutine . Also i tried with table lock and unlock before and after query. It gives same error.

`res.RowsAffected()` This also not giving any output.

In for loop i just did `fmt.Print(insert)`. It gives me memory address in array. Which keep increasing . After some point it got breaks. Here it is:

```
[{0xc4200d6070 0xc4200e0100} {0xc4200d6150 0xc42005e040} {0xc4200d61c0         0xc42005e0c0} {0xc4200d6230 0xc4203e04c0} {0xc4200d62a0 0xc4201585c0} {0xc4200d6310 0xc420469280} {0xc4200d6380 0xc420158200} {0xc4200d63f0 0xc42005fe00} {0xc4200d6460 0xc420468840} {0xc4200d64d0 0xc4200c0cc0} {0xc4200d6540 0xc4200e0a40} {0xc4200d65b0 0xc42005f480} {0xc4200d6620 0xc4200c1a80} {0xc4200d6690 0xc420254bc0} {0xc4200d6700 0xc4200e0200}] 0}insert into trans_tag_master set clientid=69,tag='tag1', adddate=now() ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tagstatus=1
```

The memory is keep increasing and after some point it exceed limit of prepare statement. How i can avoid this. Thanks

Comment: Not ignoring the errors would be a good start. I bet that `insert.Exec()` returns a (probably useful) error message (which you're ignoring).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker the same error m getting in ```err``` also

Comment: ```Exec``` It self not returning data. Its just gives above error

Comment: @AshishTiwari: if exec is returning an error, then you need to handle that error.

Comment: @JimB i handled its not giving me any mysql error. Just giving me above error.  Which i cannot understand.

Comment: You're not "handling" an error _somewhere_, because you're getting a nil pointer where you're not expecting it. Please show a complete example, with how you're handling the errors since that is most likely the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be silly question but i would like to answer of my own question. Got answer from https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/743 . Go-mysql library was making connection continuously. Because of which i got connection refused error. @Carpetsmoker  @jimB you guys was correct i was ignoring the error. In error i got message `connection refused`. I also posted whole code on above link. I set below param in my code:

```
DB.SetMaxIdleConns(10)
DB.SetMaxOpenConns(10)
DB.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Second * 10)
```

It start works. Now its not closing or keeps connected for given time. Thanks guys for your support.